# Android : Implement intent to autocompletetextview

Tags: android, android-intent, autocompletetextview

I'm new and trying to understand more about intent. I stumble upon `autocompletetextview`. How can I implement intent so that different suggestion will go to different activity. For example, when I clicked the First suggestion, it will move to the First page and when Second suggestion is clicked, Second page will come out.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            final String[] List= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.List);
            ArrayAdapter<String> Adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,List);

            AutoCompleteTextView AutoComplete=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.auto);
            AutoComplete.setThreshold(2);
            AutoComplete.setAdapter(Adapter);

            AutoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, First.class);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),(CharSequence)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
     }
```

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">AutoComplete</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string-array name="List">
    <item >First</item>
    <item>Second</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Thank you.

Comment: please go through basic development guide https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Comment: Please put the code for intent I know its crash but still i want to know the intent implementation which you have perform

Comment: @MohitTrivedi Alright, just updated the intent

Comment: @Mint okie now can you please provide full Main Activity code for same?

Comment: @MohitTrivedi Just did :)

Comment: Okie MainActivity seems like fine priovide me the First Actiity you implemented & logcat aslo

Comment: @MohitTrivedi The first activity, I just put the hello world

Comment: Okie but provide me the logcat for same

Comment: @MohitTrivedi Updated. Is that the right logcat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124693/discussion-between-mohit-trivedi-and-mint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register your First Activity in manifest file Dear

```
         <activity
            android:name=".First"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
```

it will Solved your problem

**Edited**

Happy Codding!!!

Replace this code with yours

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if(arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString().equals("First")){

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, First.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
}else if(arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString().equals("Second")){
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
}


                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),(CharSequence)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: That was careless of me. It worked but both suggestion will go to the same activity. How can I implement them so that they will move to separate activity?

Comment: will you please more elaborate ?

Comment: What I really what to implement is when I clicked on the first suggestion, the First Activity will be shown and when I clicked on Second suggestion, the Second activity will be shown. I've no idea how to make the suggestion go to separate activity. @MohitTrivedi

Comment: I get it now. It work perfectly. Thank you for your time mohit :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
autocompleteview.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //... your stuff here
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected (AdapterView<?> parent) {
        //... your stuff here
    }
})
```

Comment: It doesn't work and I can't seem to put the toast inside the `onItemSelected'